# How to change page on android application?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I'm a newbie of android. I already designed my application consists of many pages.
Anyone have a source code or anything which can let me know how to build it.
For example : When I click a button, I want it changes page to next page.
Thank you ka :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run through the [First App Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).  This will help you get an idea of how to manage `Activities` in android, which I believe is similar to the "pages" you are talking about.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 3):

You need to read up on how to develop for android.  Start with the [Hello World tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html), then work through the other tutorials.  Then read the [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).